# Why Double not Float

Tags: ojalgo

Why inferred type is Double and not Float?

```
final Array1D<Double> doubles = Array1D.factory(Primitive32Array.FACTORY).makeFilled(10, new Uniform());
```

Or put it differently, what is difference between `Primitive32Array.FACTORY` and `Primitive64Array.FACTORY`?

Comment: Having no knowledge whatsoever of ojalgo, I'd say the 32 only supports 32 bit float and 64 supports a double since there are double the bits. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: That is what I expected too. But apparently compiler insist on Double not Float..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's for historical reasons. Originally float arrays/matrices was not supported in ojAlgo, and `<Double>` naturally always referred to an underlying double[].

Now ojAlgo has partial support for float[], but only as space saving "primitive" arrays. Everything internal to `Primitive32Array` (as an example) is float and float[], but its API is still `<Double>`.

In ojAlgo `<Double>` essentially means "primitive".

Full support for float (for the matrices and linear algebra) is contemplated. When/if that happens `<Double>` may be replaced by `<Number>` to indicate anything "primitive".